# Problem in Supremum of cosets .

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ be a nonempty set and let $f\colon X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$  have bounded range in $\mathbb{R}$. If $a\in\mathbb{R}$, show that
$$\sup(a+f(x))=a+\sup(f(x)).$$
*I know above condition but facing it hard to prove.*

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried? The more you can tell us about your thoughts and efforts, the better we can tailor answers to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, it means that, if you move graph of $f$ vertically, then all bounds also move.

More general, if $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is bounded above, then $a+\sup A=\sup(a+A)$:

First, $a+b\le a+\sup A$ for all $b\in A$. Therefore $\sup(a+A)\le a+\sup A$.

Now, supose not equality. Then, $\sup(a+A)-a<\sup A$. Thus, there is $b\in A$ such that $\sup(a+A)-a<b\le\sup A$. But $b=a+b-a\le\sup(a+A)-a<b$. This contradiction shows that inequality is not possible.

Then, in particular, if $A=\{f(x)\}$, the result follows.